# Google Tag Manager Session Cookie Secure Attribute Issue

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, session-cookies, google-tag-manager

Within the webconfig file of the server, we have setup the cookies to use a secure attribute.

Google Tag Manager seems to be conflicting with this, causing a double add to cart to occur on the website itself. The loading bar on the website indicates that the click fires ones, then after loading 20% of the way, refires itself again.

Does anyone have any experience with what the issue might be?

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely the httpOnly attribute is enabled and GTM cannot access the cookie, so anything that is based on cookies will fail. As to why this causes double transactions you would need to share more of your setup - this should not usually cause multiple click events, so I would suspect that you use cookie values in some custom javascript that now doesn't work because it cannot access the cookie.

Comment: Thank you Eike, I believe that you may be right about this as I did consider this as well. When I created and added a new GTM tag to the website, it all worked the way it should with no issues.